# Specific button refuses to work in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have two buttons which seem to be have identical features. When i put "switchMode" method in "buttonMode" it doesn't work. But when I put "switchMode" in "buttonBackLight" it works alright although I don't change anything.

Here are the buttons:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMode"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="switchMode"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.584" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonBackLight"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.399" />
```

Here is the method:

```
public void switchMode(View view) {
        if(mainScreenViewsAreVisible) {
            twentyFourHoursFormat = !twentyFourHoursFormat;
            swapTimeFormatVisibility();
           }
        if(stopWatchViewsAreVisible){
            isRunning = true;
           }
        }
```

Comment: What kind of layout you're using for those buttons?

Comment: ConstraintLayout. The project itself simulates digital watch which has three buttons.

Comment: You see both buttons on the layout? Try Changing the text of those `Button`s and check out again.

Comment: I see both buttons on the layout. They contain no text at all. I tried putting buttonMode in the different spot, still not working

Comment: Paste of your java code with click register of both buttons

Comment: I'm sorry I found the solution. There was another listener in Activity which listened to buttonMode. I've deleted it and the button started to work. Should I delete this question?